# Combine street number and route in Address autocomplete api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Googles address autocomplete doesn't combine the street number and route(street name) into a single field as far as I can tell.  I would like to do that in my form but my result is NaN. Here is my code:

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="js/ass5.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/ass5.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>
<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td colspan="3"><input class="field" id="address" disabled="true"></input></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
              id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

and the javascript:

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}


// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }
// combine street_number and route to become address
var newAddress = place.address_components.street_number + place.address_components.route;
var el = document.getElementById('address');
el.textContent = newAddress;

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
// [END region_geolocation]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="js/finalproject.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/ass5.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

<body onLoad="initialize()">
<div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true"></input>
    <input type="hidden" class="field" id="route" disabled="true"></input>
    <input type="hidden" class="field" id="country" disabled="true"></input>
<table id="address">

     <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="address1" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true"></input></td>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Phone Number</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="phone"></input></td>
      </tr>

      </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}


// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }
// combine street_number and route to become address
/*
var newAddress = place.address_components.street_number + place.address_components.route;
var el = document.getElementById('address');
el.textContent = newAddress;
*/

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('address1').value = 
    place.address_components[0]['long_name'] + ' ' +
    place.address_components[1]['long_name'];
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
// [END region_geolocation]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no properties

```
place.address_components.street_number
```

and

```
place.address_components.route
```

You must iterate over `place.address_components` and check if the types-array contains the particular feature(as seen in the loop at the end of the function)

```
function fillInAddress() {
  var components  = {
                        street_number: 'short_name',
                        route: 'long_name'
                    },
      address     = [],
      place       = autocomplete.getPlace();

      for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (components[addressType]) {
          var val = place.address_components[i][components[addressType]];
          address[(addressType===route)?'unshift':'push'](val)
        }
      }
      //I simply make an alert, because it's not clear what you're trying to achieve,
      //in your current code the form-fields(except autocomplete)  are redundant
      if(!address.length){
        alert('n/a');
      }
      else{
        alert(address.join(' '));
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//this combines both street number and street name into a new input section
//with ad id of 'address1'
//here is the HTML input field
//<input type="field" id="address1" aria-required="true">

function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    // Initialize fulladdress for when we combine street number and street name
    var fullAddress="";

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details,
    // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];

        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            // retrieve first value (street number)
            switch(i){
                case 0:
                    fullAddress= val;
                    fullAddress= fullAddress.concat(" ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fullAddress= fullAddress.concat(val);
                    document.getElementById("address1").value = fullAddress;
                    break;
                default:
                    document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This is a little late but the above code grabs the street number first, adds it to the 'fullAddress' string, then it grabs the street name and concatenates it to the string. At this point 'fullAddress' contains the users full street address. Now all that's left is to create a new HTML input section with the id 'address1' that will display the new full address to the user.